# I want to add new line before 'http' in every line in text file with python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open text file and edit it, so I will add new line before 'http' in every line in text file, so in every line that contain 'http' the new line will be added before it, hence'http' will be moved to new line with the rest of characters that come after it and so on with every line in the text file
I will appreciate your help and thank you in advance for any kind of help

Comment: Have you tried search and replace 'http' with '\nhttp' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
with open("filename.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    content = f.read();

content = content.replace("http", "\nhttp");

with open("filename.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    content = f.write(content);
```

Where `"filename.txt"` is the path to your text file.